# How to access variable value from ts file to html file using angular?

Tags: html, angular, angular12

front-layout.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-front-layout',
  templateUrl: './front-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./front-layout.component.css']
})
export class FrontLayoutComponent implements OnInit {

  host:any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.host = "http://localhost:4200";

  }

}
```

front-layout.component.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="'{{ host }}'/assets/front/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="'{{ host }}'/assets/front/plugins/select2/css/select2.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <script src="'{{ host }}'/assets/front/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code I simply declare `host` and try to access in my html component but it throw an error i.e. `src/app/component/front/front-layout/front-layout.component.ts:5:16 - error NG2008: Could not find stylesheet file ''{{ host }}'/assets/front/css/bootstrap.min.css' linked from the template.`. No idea why variable not working? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: try to includes these files in your angular.json file. or if you just use it without host. then it will automatically point to base url and will access assets folder and file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should move the links and scripts to `index.html`, and from there, use this path

```
./assets/front/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js
```

Comment: I tried but it's not working :(

Comment: you could move all that code to `index.html`, leaving only the `div` with the class there, and there (in the component).

Comment: @arsha I updated my quesiton, see if that works

Comment: I didn't because I have two layout one is for admin and second is for front so, that's why I am not using `index.html`

Comment: What do you mean? Angular is SPA, everything that you see happening, happens in `index.html`, you can have how many layouts as you want, you don't need to worry about it

Answer (score 0):

To load the content of `host`

Must be `[href]` and `[src]` instead of `href` and `src`

---

and instead of
`href="'{{ host }}'/assets/front/css/bootstrap.min.css"`

---

must be
`[href]="host + '/assets/front/css/bootstrap.min.css'"`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" [href]="host + '/assets/front/css/bootstrap.min.css'">
    <link rel="stylesheet" [href]="host + '/assets/front/plugins/select2/css/select2.min.css'">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        
    </div>
    <script [src]="host + '/assets/front/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js'"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

But in angular all this stuff is done in `index.html`

This is how you dynamically load scripts in angular from any component

---

### script.service.ts

```
import { Injectable , Renderer2, RendererFactory2 } from '@angular/core';
import { ScriptStore } from '../../store/store.script';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class LoadScriptService {
  private scripts: any = {};
  private renderer: Renderer2;

  constructor(rendererFactory: RendererFactory2) {
    this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
    this.getScripts();
  }

  private getScripts() {   
    ScriptStore.forEach((script: any) => {
      this.scripts[script.name] = { src: script.src, loaded: script.loaded }
    });
  }

  load(scriptName: string[]) {
    scriptName.forEach((script: any) => {
      this.loadScript(script);
    });
  }

  private loadScript(name: string) {
    if (this.scripts[name].loaded) {
      return;
    }

    let script = this.renderer.createElement('script');
    script.src = this.scripts[name].src;

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    this.scripts[name].loaded = true;
  }
}
```

---

### store.script.ts

```
import { Script } from "../interfaces/schema.script";

export const ScriptStore: Script[] = [
    { name: 'typeform', src: '//embed.typeform.com/next/embed.js', loaded: false }
     * import here script info in object format. ex:
     * { name: 'script1', src: 'url1', loaded: false } 
     * { name: 'script2', src: 'url2', loaded: false }
     * { name: 'script3', src: 'url3', loaded: false }
];
```

---

### interfaces/schema.script.ts

```
export interface Script {
    name: string;
    src: string;
    loaded: boolean;
}
```

Then you import `script.service` in any component and call `load` function `this.scriptService.load('script's name')` or `this.scriptService.load('script's name1', 'script's name2', 'script's name3')`

Comment: I just provided an example of how to bind variable and concat it with a string. But you should not you this particular code in production. This is a `xxs` vulnerability. See the docs https://angular.io/guide/security#xss

Comment: I tried your code but when I inspect element then I got blank stylesheet `<link _ngcontent-qbt-c50="" rel="stylesheet">` href and link is missing.

Comment: It is empty because First: it fires security error and Second: this is done in `index.html`, if you put that in some random component, angular will  refuse to apply them. If you want to dynamically add `script` or `link` to `head` or `body` you have to do it from `ts`. You have acces to them from any component.

My answer explains how the variable binding is done in this case, but script loading is another question. I will add some example of script loading